# Select all fields as json string as new field in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am using Flink Table API. I have a table definition that I want to select all fields and convert them to a JSON string in a new field.

My table has three fields; `a: String, b: Int, c: Timestamp.`

If I do

```
INSERT INTO kinesis
SELECT a, b, c from my_table
```

The kinesis stream has json records;

```
{
  "a" : value,
  "b": value,
  "c": value
}
```

However, I want something similar to Spark's functions;

```
INSERT INTO kinesis
SELECT "constant_value" as my source, to_json(struct(*)) as playload from my_table
```

So, expected result is;

```
{
  "my_source": "constant_value",
  "payload": "json string from the first example that has a,b,c"
}
```

I can't see any `to_json` or `struct()` functions in Flink. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 2):

you might have to implement your own user-defined aggregate function.

this is what i did, here i assume the input to the UDF looks like

to_json('col1', col1, 'col2', col2)

```
public class RowToJson extends ScalarFunction {
    public String eval(@DataTypeHint(inputGroup = InputGroup.ANY) Object... row) throws Exception {
        if(row.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new Exception("Wrong key/value pairs!");
        }

        String json = IntStream.range(0, row.length).filter(index -> index % 2 == 0).mapToObj(index -> {
            String name = row[index].toString();
            Object value = row[index+1];
            ... ...
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));
        return json;
    }
}
```

if you expect udf could be used for group by, you have to extend your udf class from AggregateFunction

```
public class RowsToJson extends AggregateFunction<String, List<String>>{
    @Override
    public String getValue(List<String> accumulator) {
        return accumulator.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> createAccumulator() {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void accumulate(List<String> acc, @DataTypeHint(inputGroup = InputGroup.ANY) Object... row) throws Exception {
        if(row.length % 2 != 0) {
            throw new Exception("Wrong key/value pairs!");
        }
        String json = IntStream.range(0, row.length).filter(index -> index % 2 == 0).mapToObj(index -> {
            String name = row[index].toString();
            Object value = row[index+1];
            ... ...
        }).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));
        acc.add(json);
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not quite answer the question. Do you mind sharing your code/guidance?

Answer (score 0):

From Flink 1.15, JSON_OBJECT SQL function can help you to create JSON field from individual columns: [flink json functions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/functions/systemfunctions/#json-functions)

> SELECT JSON_OBJECT('col1' value col1, 'col2' value col2) FROM table